# Execute a Table Valued Function as an IQueryable in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework, I was using Linq-to-SQL and it is working great, but when I want to create a WCF Data Service I receive a lot of errors from the service, so I decided to move to EF.

But my problem is TVF (Table Valued Function), in my database I have a lot of TVF that return data for each logged in user plus the user rights of specified object, for example I have a table `Records` and a TVF `uf_SelectUserRecords(@UID BIGINT)`. I want to execute this function and return its result in place of `Records` table.

In Linq-to-SQL it worked fine but in EF I can't make it run, the problem is when I add the TVF to the model (through some tricks, since EF designer does not support it) the result of TVF is not `IQueryable` but an `IEnumerable`, so I can't return it in WCF Data Service.

Is there any way that I can execute a function as a table?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?  Looks like [better support for TVFs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh859577) exists in EF 5.

Comment: I'm using EF5 in VS2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every where I see that EF 5  have support for TVF, but in my project I see no support for it. why? I was using .NET 4 and new features of EF 5 is only available for .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the result to an `IQueryable` by using `AsQueryable()`:

```
IEnumerable<Record> result = {call TVF};
IQueryable<Record> query = result.AsQueryable();
return query;
```

Comment: would that execute the queries against the database or against the objects in memory? Will the entire enumerable be loaded into memory from the database and then queries run on it?

Comment: It depends on what the underlying type is.  If it already implements `IQueryable` then it should.  I've never tried it so I can't say for certain.